# Get all jsonb values in one column for usage in to_tsvector

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I got a table jsonb table `t_1`, that contains column `column_1` with jsonb type and i need to convert in to table with string, that is concatination of jsonb values

Here is a script

```
    CREATE TABLE t_1 (
       ID serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       column_1 jsonb NOT NULL
    );


    INSERT INTO t_1 (column_1)
    VALUES
    (
       '{ "01": "Lily Bush", "03": "prod2uct"}'
    ),
    (
       '{ "41": "Josh William", "12": "product7"}'
    ),
    (
       '{ "07": "Mary Clark", "items" : "product2"}'
    );
```

I tried this:

`SELECT distinct jsonb_array_elements_text(column_1 -> jsonb_object_keys(column_1)) AS Actor  FROM t_1`

But this return 'unable to extract elements from scalar'

I tried this:

`SELECT tiket, string_agg(column_2, ', ') as list FROM( 
SELECT column_1 ->> jsonb_object_keys(column_1) as column_2, id as tiket FROM t_1 ) as foo1
GROUP BY tiket`

but here is inner select

How can i get all jsonb values in one column without inner select, something like in first query?

I need it to use in `to_tsvector`

I need to use it in

```
setweight(
to_tsvector('simple', column_with_json::text),
'A'
)
```

But `column_with_json::text` not what i need, i need to get values, without keys

Any examples?

Comment: Don't use set returning functions (like jsonb_object_keys) in the SELECT list. Use them in the `FROM` part

Comment: I need to use it in

    setweight(
    to_tsvector('simple', column_with_json::text),
    'A'
    )

But `column_with_json::text` not what i need, i need to get values, without keys

Any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_each_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) in a lateral join:

```
SELECT id, string_agg(value, ', ') AS list
FROM t_1
CROSS JOIN jsonb_each_text(column_1)
GROUP BY id

 id |          list          
----+------------------------
  1 | Lily Bush, prod2uct
  2 | product7, Josh William
  3 | Mary Clark, product2
(3 rows)
```

If you want to use the resulting aggregated value in a condition, use `HAVING` clause, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, string_agg(value, ', ') AS list
FROM t_1
CROSS JOIN jsonb_each_text(column_1)
GROUP BY id
HAVING string_agg(value, ', ') LIKE '%Lily%'
```

or a derived table and `WHERE` clause in a wrapper query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, string_agg(value, ', ') AS list
    FROM t_1
    CROSS JOIN jsonb_each_text(column_1)
    GROUP BY id
    ) s
WHERE list LIKE '%Lily%'
```

Both approaches are basically equivalent, in typical cases they generate the same query plan. In both the aggregation is calculated only once.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that i need to call some function in where clause,

Comment: I don't understand. There is no mention of a function in the question. Anyway, just add the `WHERE` clause if you need one.

Comment: I need to use it in

    setweight(
    to_tsvector('simple', column_with_json::text),
    'A'
    )

But `column_with_json::text` not what i need, i need to get values, without keys

Any examples?

Comment: Thanks!!!
Return from vacation,

Check the answer,

Click to set as rigth answer=))